# How to read HTTP request headers in a WCF web service?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

In a WCF web service, how does one read an HTTP/HTTPS request header? In this case, i'm trying to determine the original URL host the client used. This might be in the X-Forwarded-Host header from a load balancer, or in the Host header if it's direct-box.

I've tried `OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.FindHeader` but i think this is looking at SOAP headers rather than HTTP headers.

So, how to read HTTP headers? Surely this is a simple question and i'm missing something obvious.

EDIT - @sinfere's answer was almost exactly what i needed. For completeness, here's what i ended up with:

```
IncomingWebRequestContext request = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest;
WebHeaderCollection headers = request.Headers;
string host = null;

if (headers["X-Forwarded-Host"] != null)
    host = headers["X-Forwarded-Host"];
else if (headers["Host"] != null)
    host = headers["Host"];
else 
    host = defaulthost; // set from a config value
```

Comment: use ... WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers

Comment: While technically not a header, WCF disposes the content from the original HTTP Request so you will not be able to access the content of a Request inside your service. You can however, grab this before a service method is invoked inside a OperationsHandler

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try `WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers`

I use following codes to see all headers :

```
IncomingWebRequestContext request = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest;
WebHeaderCollection headers = request.Headers;

Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine(request.Method + " " + request.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri.AbsolutePath);
foreach (string headerName in headers.AllKeys)
{
  Console.WriteLine(headerName + ": " + headers[headerName]);
}
Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------");
```

Comment: Not all of this worked (the second `Consol.WriteLine` line) but the rest got me there. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 25):

This is how I read them in one of my Azure WCF web services.

```
IncomingWebRequestContext woc = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest;

string applicationheader = woc.Headers["HeaderName"];
```