# How can I deserialize a custom SOAP header in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I'm attempting to add a custom header to all SOAP requests over WCF.  I found [this fantastic article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mohamedg/archive/2012/10/21/adding-custom-soap-headers-in-wcf.aspx) on how to do exactly this.  My `MessageHeader` class looks like this:

```
public class OperatorNameMessageHeader : MessageHeader
{
    private string opName;

    public const string HeaderName = "OperatorNameMessageHeader";
    public const string HeaderNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/scout";

    public override string Name { get { return HeaderName; } }
    public override string Namespace { get { return HeaderNamespace; } }

    public string OperatorName
    {
        get { return opName; }
        set { opName = value; }
    }

    public OperatorNameMessageHeader()
    {
    }

    public OperatorNameMessageHeader(string operatorName)
    {
        opName = operatorName;
    }

    protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("OperatorName", opName);
    }
}
```

One thing the article does *not* say is how to *read* the value on the server.  According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877591/how-to-read-http-request-headers-in-a-wcf-web-service), you can use `OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders` to read these headers.  When I look at these `MessageHeaders` under the debugger, I see 3 headers including my custom one.  So, it's definitely showing up in the SOAP data.  However, when I call `GetHeader`:

```
OperatorNameMessageHeader test = msgHeaders.GetHeader<OperatorNameMessageHeader>(OperatorNameMessageHeader.HeaderName, OperatorNameMessageHeader.HeaderNamespace);
```

Then `test.OperatorName` is null.  Basically, I'm just getting back an empty `OperatorNameMessageHeader` object that hasn't been deserialized from the data in the SOAP.

My next step was to run the WCF tracing tool.  When I do this, I can verify the custom header is *indeed* being sent across the wire:

```
<MessageHeaders>
   <ActivityId CorrelationId="66a7c5b6-3548-4f3c-9120-4484af76b64b" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">f9bef03b-4e7b-4e84-b327-5e79814d9933</ActivityId>
   <OperatorNameMessageHeader xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/scout">
      <OperatorName>Correct Operator Name</OperatorName>
   </OperatorNameMessageHeader>
   <To d4p1:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://localhost:90/IRolesAndResourcesManager</To>
   <Action d4p1:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IRolesAndResourcesManager/Authenticate</Action>
</MessageHeaders>
```

So, the server *has* the data, I just can't *get* to it.  What's the solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm having this issue at the moment, Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Declan - Never did!  I ended up figuring out a way to do the same thing using an HTTP header though.  The information is not in SOAP, and only works with HTTP, so that might be a deal breaker for some.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I'm having this same issue. you should put a bounty on this question :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, and was able to make it work as follows:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = OperatorNameMessageHeader.HeaderNamespace)]
public class OperatorNameMessageHeader
{
    public const string HeaderName = "OperatorNameMessageHeader";
    public const string HeaderNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/scout";

    [DataMember]
    public string OperatorName { get; set; }
}
```

With that, I can read the header as follows:

```
public static OperatorNameMessageHeader DeserializeSoap(string xml)
{
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
    {
        var m = System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, MessageVersion.Soap11);
        var operatorNameHeader = m.Headers.GetHeader<OperatorNameMessageHeader>(OperatorNameMessageHeader.HeaderName, OperatorNameMessageHeader.HeaderNamespace);

        return operatorNameHeader;
    }
}
```

Notice I'm using WCF to deserialize the XML string and therefore needed to use the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes - without them, it won't work. Not sure if you need to actually derive from `MessageHeader` for your case, but for me that isn't necessary in order to read custom headers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your suggestion helped me. However for some reason I was only able to deserialize 1 property from the soap header. In order to deserialize 3 properties I had to split my header definition in 3 parts and deserialize it 3 times. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I have to read a username annd password from headers. I found a temporal solution, I'm using XmlDictionaryReader. But with this code I only look for the names, I still can improve it but works for the moment. I have it for VB, will be something similar for C#

```
        Dim username As String = ""
        Dim password As String = ""
        Dim usernameTokenId As String = ""
        Dim passwordType As String = ""

        For i As Integer = 0 To OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.Count - 1
            Dim mhi As Channels.MessageHeaderInfo = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.Item(i)
            Dim headers As Channels.MessageHeaders = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers
            If mhi.Name.Equals("Security") Then
                Dim xr As XmlDictionaryReader = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetReaderAtHeader(i)
                xr.MoveToContent()
                While xr.MoveToNextAttribute()
                    Console.Write(" {0}='{1}'", xr.Name, xr.Value)
                End While
                Do
                    Select Case xr.NodeType
                        Case XmlNodeType.Element
                            If xr.LocalName.Equals("Username") Then
                                username = xr.ReadElementContentAsString()
                            End If
                            If xr.LocalName.Equals("Password") Then
                                password = xr.ReadElementContentAsString()
                            End If

                            While xr.MoveToNextAttribute()
                                If xr.LocalName.Equals("Id") Then
                                    usernameTokenId = xr.Value
                                End If
                                If xr.LocalName.Equals("Type") Then
                                    passwordType = xr.Value
                                End If
                            End While
                        Case XmlNodeType.Attribute

                            'Case XmlNodeType.Text
                            '    Console.Write(xr.Value)
                            'Case XmlNodeType.EndElement
                            '    Console.Write("</{0}>", xr.Name)
                    End Select
                Loop While xr.Read()
            End If


            Dim name As String = mhi.Name
        Next
```