# WCF MessageHeader attribute does not deserialized

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, messagecontract

I am developing the the SOAP based web services in the WCF.

My client sending the request to the WCF services with the following SOAP request xml:

```
<e:Envelope xmlns:e="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" e:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <e:Header>
        <me:RequestHead xmlns:me="http://www.my-namespace.org/header/abc" >
            <ID>0</ID>
            <Green>
                <a>101</a>
                <b>0</b>
            </Green>
            <Time>1</Tim>
        </me:RequestHead>
    </e:Header>
    <e:Body>
        <m:RequestBody xmlns:m="http://www.my-namespace.org/service/abc">
            <Time>
                <hh>23</hh>
                <mm>59</mm>
                <ss>59</ss>
            </Time>            
        </m:RequestBody>
    </e:Body>
</e:Envelope>
```

I created the `MessageContract` class to pass the value to client or get the value from the client.

In `MessageContract` class there is multiple `MessageHeader` attribute property, but when request send to the server the property with `MessageHeader` attribute is not **deserialize** and it is always **null**.

In `RequestHead` tag there is prefix `me`, I think its create the problem to deserialize the XML request to the object at the WCF services

But in `RequestBody` tag there is also prefix `m` but it deserialize successfully.

When I remove the prefix `me` from the `RequestHead` tag than it worked successfully. and I got the value of the `MessageHeader` attribute property.

```
<e:Envelope xmlns:e="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" e:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <e:Header>
        <RequestHead xmlns="http://www.my-namespace.org/header/abc" >
            <ID>0</ID>
            <Green>
                <a>101</a>
                <b>0</b>
            </Green>
            <Time>1</Tim>
        </RequestHead>
    </e:Header>
    <e:Body>
        <m:RequestBody xmlns:m="http://www.my-namespace.org/service/abc">
            <hh>23</hh>
            <mm>59</mm>
            <ss>59</ss>
        </m:RequestBody>
    </e:Body>
</e:Envelope>
```

My Classes:

```
[MessageContract]
class Green
{
    [MessageHeader(Namespace = "")]
    public string a { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader(Namespace = "")]
    public string b { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract]
class RequestHead
{
    [MessageHeader(Namespace = "")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader(Namespace = "")]
    public Green green { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader(Namespace = "")]
    public int Time { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract]
class Head
{
    [MessageHeader(Namespace = "http://www.my-namespace.org/header/abc")]
    public RequestHead RequestHead { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract(Namespace = "http://www.my-namespace.org/service/abc")]
class RequestBody : Head
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public int hh { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public int mm { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public int ss { get; set; }
}
```

And my action method in the WCF services is look like this:

```
public RequestBody CheckTime(RequestBody objBody)
{

}
```

When I checked the request SOAP XML using the following code:

```
OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString();
```

It give me the full request SOAP XML with the header value also but does not deserialize it to the object.

I does not understand where I am going wrong or I am missing something.

Here is the same question asked but till now it is does not get any answered: [How can I deserialize a custom SOAP header in WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389225/how-can-i-deserialize-a-custom-soap-header-in-wcf)

Thanks for help...

Comment: The xml doesn't deserialize probably because all the namespaces in the XML do not match what is expected by the types. You might want to create a simple service operation that returns a response of type 'RequestBody', return a hand built boject of type 'RequestBody' and check out the XML that it gets serialized into.

Comment: @ParagPatil, Yes ti works if I return the hand built object to the client, But my client will be send the request with the same SOAP XML which I posted above and It will not work. And I am unable to change the client's code because My client is third party WCF. Is there any way to desalinize properly ? Thanks

Comment: There is no need to create the hand built object and send to the client. If I remove the tag prefix from the client request than it works properly.