# How can i pass an object and a string to webservice using post request using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, web-services

Am very new to angularjs and i need to post data to a web service, the service accepts two parameters, one is List of object and the other is securityToken,

Here is my code,

```
$scope.saveCompany=function(){

      // alert("Save Company!!!");

     var Companies={
        Code: 'testMartin',
        Name: 'company1',
        CompanyType : 'Tenant',
        email : 'test@yaoo.com',
        Fax : 4235353,
        ParentID : 1

    };
    $http({
        url:'http://localhost/masters/smstools.svc/json/SaveComapnies',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $.param(Companies),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "text/json",
        }

    }).success(function(response){
        alert ("Success");
    }).error(function(error){
        alert ("Save company!");
    });
```

how can i pass the security token with the companies object as a separate paramenter. my service accepts the parameters like this,

```
 public List<CompanyProfile> Save(List<CompanyProfile> CompanyList,string securityToken)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a rest call you only have 3 places were you can pass parameters data:

With **Post** and it will be part of the body, it seems this is what is your first parameter is occupying now.

With **Get** and you add the parameter to the URL `/json/SaveComapnies/mySecParam` or by queryString like /`json/SaveComapnies?sec=mySecParam` but this is not secure nor recommended for security settings.

With **header** from angular Post:

```
    **headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/json",
        "mySecVar": "mySecParamValue"
    }**
```

**Server side version:**

```
public List<CompanyProfile> Save(List<CompanyProfile> CompanyList){

    WebOperationContext current = WebOperationContext.Current;
    WebHeaderCollection headers = current.IncomingRequest.Headers;

    if (headers["mySecVar"] != null){
         // do something
    }
}
```

You can read more about it here:

[How to read HTTP request headers in a WCF web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877591/how-to-read-http-request-headers-in-a-wcf-web-service)

Comment: can you post the complete post code? i still dont get the answer!

Comment: what is your server side technology is it WCF or WebApi?

Comment: it's wcf and i have posted the interface which accepts a list and a string

Comment: @Sajeetharan I just placed a quick sample code to give you an idea what is necessary to use the headers

Comment: Problem is i cannot change the service , since it is already hosted. i can post the code of the service if you want, thanks for the help

Comment: Then my conclusion would be that your WCF does not support angular since it is not a true rest service. I may be wrong but as fas I know those are you only options.

Comment: ok can you suggest anyway to call this method from an html page?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share more information in your Backend?

If it is actually a REST Backend I would rather use an angular $resource

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource

If you want to pass json object and string as post Parameter you should stick to the $http docs

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

In the post example you can pass both params in:

```
$http.post('/yourEndpoint', {jsonObj:yourCompaniesObj, secKey:yourSecretToken})....(sucess etc)
```

Typing from my cell - if you need more code examples just tell