# How To Send Custom Header using Jquery Ajax and Retrieve the same header value in WCF Service using C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf

I try to send header value from Jquery Ajax like this

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    url:http://my url
    headers: { "CustomHeader": "myValue" }
});
```

but i can't consume this header value in wcf service using C#..If there is any way to send custom header using ajax and retrieve same header in wcf service

Thanks in advance

Comment: It should work. How you are accessing your headers.

Comment: string message = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString();

Comment: Read this link may it will help you:[Read Request Header in wcf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877591/how-to-read-http-request-headers-in-a-wcf-web-service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery's `ajax` method, I will send headers like this:

```js
$.ajax({       
    url: varUrl, // Location of the service  
    headers: {
        "Test": "Test-Value", // "Header-name" : "Header-value"          
    }       
});
```

In WCF, I will consume headers like this:

```cs
//retrieve your header value using "Header-name"...    
WebOperationContext current = WebOperationContext.Current;
WebHeaderCollection headers = current.IncomingRequest.Headers;
string Test= current.IncomingRequest.Headers.GetValues("Test")[0].ToString();
```